# How to make a better visualization for two close curves?

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
f[n_] := (1/3) ((2/3)^(n - 4))

p[s_] := ((E^(-beta/s - d s))/(Sum[E^(-beta/n - d n), {n, 4, 20}])) /. {beta -> -0.051138344977742424`, d -> 0.4013782057979059`}

DiscretePlot[{p[n], f[n]}, {n, 4, 20}, Filling -> None, Joined -> True, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[{RGBColor[0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051], 
Thick, Dashed}], Directive[{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], Thick}]}, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Style[Subscript[p, n], 
FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10", FontSize -> 30]}], {0.80, 0.68}], Ticks -> {{4, 8, 12, 16, 20}, Automatic}, 
AxesLabel -> {Style[HoldForm[n], FontSize -> 30, 
FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], 
Style[HoldForm[Subscript[P, m]], FontSize -> 30, 
FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, 
LabelStyle -> {26, GrayLevel[0]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1.3}, {0, 0.022}}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{0.035}}], FormatType -> TraditionalForm, 
ImagePadding -> 78, PlotRange -> All]
```

which gives:

[image]

The dashed curve has hidden behind the blue one. How can I make a better visualization of this? (I need to keep colors and dashed style of one.)

Comment: Change the order in ``PlotStyle`` so that the blue one is first and the dashed orange the second: ``PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Blue, Thick}], Directive[{Orange, Thick, Dashed}]}``

Comment: @Rose If you change the order of Plot arguments too, Domen's solution works

Comment: I should mention it explicitly, yeah, sorry: ``DiscretePlot[{f[n], p[n]}, {n, 4, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Blue, Thick}], Directive[{Orange, Thick, Dashed}]}]``

Comment: You can always plot the *difference* between the two curves and show that it's very close to zero.

Comment: Yep! `Plot[f[n] - p[n], {n, 0, 10}]`. To make it *extra* clear what the differences between the two functions are, you can even plot the logarithm of the square of the difference: `Plot[Log[(f[n] - p[n])^2], {n, 0, 10}]`. This all has the advantage of being *quantitative* instead of using the "by-eye" method of plotting them on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have suggested in the comment, change the order of plotted functions and the order in `PlotStyle`. Furthermore, add `None` to the `LineLegend` to only show the legend for the second curve.

```
DiscretePlot[{f[n], p[n]}, {n, 4, 20}, Filling -> None, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
     Thick}], 
   Directive[{RGBColor[0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051], Thick, 
     Dashed}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{None, 
     Style[Subscript[p, n], FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 12", 
      FontSize -> 30]}], {0.80, 0.68}], 
 Ticks -> {{4, 8, 12, 16, 20}, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style[HoldForm[n], FontSize -> 30, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 12"], 
   Style[HoldForm[Subscript[P, m]], FontSize -> 30, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 12"]}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 12"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {26, GrayLevel[0]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1.3}, {0, 0.022}}, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{0.035}}], FormatType -> TraditionalForm, 
 ImagePadding -> 78, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Note also that you do not need to provide colors explicitly, since they follow the primary color scheme, so you can write simply: `PlotStyle -> {Thick, {Thick, Dashed}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your second PlotStyle Directive from `Thick`to `Thin`

```
DiscretePlot[{p[n], f[n]}, {n, 4, 20}, Filling -> None, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[{RGBColor[0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051], 
     Thick, Dashed}], 
   Directive[{RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], Thin}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Style[Subscript[p, n], 
      FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10", FontSize -> 30]}], {0.80,
     0.68}], Ticks -> {{4, 8, 12, 16, 20}, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style[HoldForm[n], FontSize -> 30, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"], 
   Style[HoldForm[Subscript[P, m]], FontSize -> 30, 
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman 10"]}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {26, GrayLevel[0]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1.3}, {0, 0.022}}, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{0.035}}], FormatType -> TraditionalForm, 
 ImagePadding -> 78, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]